# Passing timer value to next form

Tags: windows, vb.net

I developing an application that require pass the timer value to next form. For example Form A time out is 30 seconds, If the user dont click on the screen, it will back to the Main Screen. Sames go to the Form B. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Previously I was using the MDI approach to develop.Just curious, any approach beside using MDI ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the constructor(s) of the page(s) you want to accept the timer value, like this:

```
Public Class FormA Inherits Form
    Private timerValue As Integer

    Public Sub New(_timerValue As Integer)
        timerValue = _timerValue
    End Sub

    Public Sub MethodA
        ' Do something with timerValue here
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: How do you know he is refering to WinForms?

Comment: The `windows` tag in the question and the use of the word `form`. I may be wrong, but I am pretty sure that the OP is talking about WinForms development.